# How to edit box collider more accurately in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make a collider of road going up, and I have literally no idea how to change collider so as it's not a rectangle, because it's the only way to do that with "Edit box collider" function. Can ya help?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add more box collider components to shape them as you want(Not a good idea)
or simply use `Mesh collider`

Mesh collider is recommended, I believe it gives you the result you want.